# How can I get my Ionic 4 app to long-press select text?

Tags: ios, ionic4

I need for my Ionic 4 app to handle the long-press text select/copy/paste on iOS.

I have tried the following in my global.scss with no success:

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: text !important;
    -moz-user-select: text !important;
    -ms-user-select: text !important;
    user-select: text !important; 
}
```

and also creating a class that can be included per element:

```
.selectable {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text; 
}
```

then

```
<div class='selectable'>This should be selectable</div>
```

None of these are working.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.text-select {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```

then use the class on the specific element you want. sample below

```
<ion-text class="text-select">Test</ion-text>
```

Comment: This works fine on my phone and most of the iPhones here, but there are 3 phones (so far) where it doesn't work.  Any tips on why it wouldn't work on these other phones?

Comment: what are the model of those phones? is it android or ios?

Comment: iPhones.  I have a 7 and it works on mine.  My coworker has a 7 as well and it doesn't work on his.  A couple of 11's where it works on one, but not on the other.